# Can iOS APP play downloaded MP4 files in custom window?

Tags: ios, video, playback

We have an iOS APP project which will play video in our custom window and would like to play the downloaded video files. According to such kind of demand, is that possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. Please check the documents for [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) . This allows you to play a video and managing your own view hierarchy/custom views. To play a video inline, you need to use the `view` property of your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance an put it into your view hierarchy. The features of MPMoviePlayerController have changed with iOS 3.2, so while using it, be sure to only use features for your deployment target.